# mysql_fetch_array (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, arrays, fetch

I'm a beginner and I have a error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\index.php on line 35
```

and the code...

```
$sresult = mysql_query("SELECT code, location FROM banners");
while ($row_s = mysql_fetch_array($sresult))
{
    $banner[$row_s["location"]]=$row_s["code"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sresult = mysql_query("SELECT code, location FROM banners");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row_s = mysql_fetch_array($sresult))
{
    $banner[$row_s["location"]]=$row_s["code"];
}
```

And check what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the query.
try:

```
$result = mysql_query("..");
if(!$result){
  echo "Query error: " . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: `or die()` :-( :-( http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die -- I never understood why people keep using this ... Or even *started* using it in the first place...

Comment: Agreed on die(), I, personally, have NEVER used it in my own code, but it was the first thing that popped in mind when writing here, strange :)